# What is numpy.dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m]) in numpy.dot() documentation?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I was trying to understand difference between np.dot and np.matmul and in the docs of [np.dot()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) there is this code
`dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])`. What does it mean?

> If a is an N-D array and b is an M-D array (where M>=2), it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last axis of b:

What does above statement mean? is it like a property that it will satisfy?

```
a = np.arange(3*4*5*6).reshape((3,4,5,6))
b = np.arange(3*4*5*6)[::-1].reshape((5,4,6,3))
np.dot(a, b)[2,3,2,1,2,2]
499128
sum(a[2,3,2,:] * b[1,2,:,2])
499128
```

Where does this [2,3,2,1,2,2] index in above example come from? or is it just an arbitrary index considered for example.

By the way how does one know the output shape for dot product with more than 2 dimensions, like `m x n . n x m = m x m`. How was the np.dot() even calculated in the above example when the last dimension of "a" and first dimension of "b" not being equal? I will remove this second question if this counts as separate subject.